# How can I mount or extract TWRP Nandroid backups in Windows?

Tags: backup, windows, twrp, nandroid

Every so often, I need to extract files from a backup. I'm aware Titanium Backup can do this, and there are no doubt other apps capable of the same, but I want to do it on my PC where the backups actually reside.

Files with the `.ext4.win` extension are simple enough -- just open in WinRAR or similar -- but `.emmc.win` files are another story. Are there any tools to extract, or, ideally, mount `.emmc.win` files in Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ext4.win` is a posix tar archive according to the `file` command.

The only partitions I have in a TWRP backup that are `emmc.win` are boot recovery and system. Those are basically the same as `boot.img`, `recovery.img`, and `system.img` but renamed.

These are `ext` partition images and you can read the contents of them with [ext2read](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/) tool.

Comment: I can open these archives with 7-Zip but I can't extract anything, it gives errors. Any idea how to make it work with 7-Zip?

Comment: ext2read doesn't work BTW, I tried opening image but nothing happens on Windows 10 1803

Comment: 7-zip also not working in win10